# Openshift Build Failed/Cancelled

Tags: git, jsp, jenkins, cloud, openshift

I am going to deploy JSP site on Openshift Redhat Cloud Server.
My domain is http://jsp-moristems.rhcloud.com.

I cloned the application using Git, removed src folder and pom.xml file, copied ROOT.war (which is the war file I am going to deploy) under /webapps, and pushed.

But I see this error:

```
E:\git\jsp [master ↑]> git push
Warning: Permanently added 'jsp-moristems.rhcloud.com,107.21.78.52' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 43.44 MiB | 338.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Executing Jenkins build.
remote:
remote: You can track your build at https://red-moristems.rhcloud.com/job/jsp-build
remote:
remote: Waiting for build to schedule...............................
remote: **BUILD FAILED/CANCELLED**
remote: Please see the Jenkins log for more details via 'rhc tail'
remote: !!!!!!!!
remote: Deployment Halted!
remote: If the build failed before the deploy step, your previous
remote: build is still running. Otherwise, your application may be
remote: partially deployed or inaccessible.
remote: Fix the build and try again.
remote: !!!!!!!!
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control post-receive' for /var/lib/openshift/5799d1f889f5cf15800000a8/jenkins-client
remote:
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://5799d1f889f5cf15800000a8@jsp-moristems.rhcloud.com/~/git/jsp.git
ad41e5f..2bd7925 master -> master
```

I followed as exactly openshift guide says, so I can't figure out what I did wrong.
Please help me if you have ever met such issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be deploying an already built war file using Jenkins.  Jenkins is specifically looking for the pom.xml and src folders so that it can compile the code and build your project.  If you want to just deploy a war file, remove/turn off jenkins and it should be fine.